# Loop for rename columns in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I'm trying to rename the columns of a Dataframe with this loop. Nevertheless, just rename with the first item from the list (column) which contains the names.

```
for col in df_wine.columns[1:]:
    for names in column:
        df_wine = df_wine.rename(columns = {col : names})
```

I expect that takes each item(name) from the list.

Comment: This is pointless.  You are renaming each column over and over and over.  What are you really trying to do?  Remember that `.rename` can rename all of your columns at once.  Just build a single mapping.

Comment: No need to use loop, use `df_wine.columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']` or in your case it might be `df_wine.columns = ['col1'] + column`

Comment: I know, but i'm trying to make it with the loop taking each item from the list(column) to rename each column from the original dataframe.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do. Please [edit] to include a [mcve] with a sample of your input and your expected output based on that input. At the moment, it looks like you're trying to assign each value in your dataframe to the column names in turn

Comment: But that's not what your nested loop does.  Your loop says "for EACH column, rename it with EVERY name from the new set".  If the old names are A, B, C and the new names are D, E, F, your code will rename A to D, then A to E, then A to F, then B to D, then B to E, then B to F, then C to D, etc.  After each one is renamed to D, the old name is no longer found.

Comment: if you need to use iteration, try `for old,new in list(zip(df_wine.columns, ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'])):   df_wine = df_wine.rename(columns = {old : new})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
old = df_wine.columns[1:]
mapping = { o:n for o,n in zip(old,column) }
df_wine.rename( columns=mapping, inplace=True )
```

Just build a dictionary that maps old to new and do it in one shot.

Comment: Be sure to upvote and check the "answer" checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Generally in pandas unless you pass `inplace=True` the operation doesn't modify the original dataframe, it returns a new one, i.e you need to do

```
df = df.rename()
```

Second you need to pass a map (i.e. dictionary) between the old and new columns. You're passing a map between one old column and a list of all the new columns repeatedly.

Instead you just need to do

```
df = df.rename({"old_col_1":"new_col_1", "old_col_2":"new_col_2", ...})
```

You'll probably need to use `dictionary comprehension` to build this dictionary but its hard to tell from your example what the association is between the old and new columns.